# Github action skipping release file

Tags: github-actions

I own an npm package and decided to create Github actions to automate processes effectively.

- `main.yml` - handle Node CI. on every push to the master branch, the action will install the dependencies and build through multiple operating systems.
- `release.yml` - required to release a new version to npm and Github Releases. It'll fire on every commit tag which begins with "v" (e.g., "v0.1.4").

However, the `release.yml` action is being skipped while pushing to git with the commit tag.

How to fire the `release.yml` file? but still, wait for `main.yml` to finish the entire workflow?

I would appreciate your assistance.

`main.yml` action:

```
name: Node Continous Integration

on: 
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build on Node ${{ matrix.node }} and ${{ matrix.os }}

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: ['10.x', '12.x', '14.x']
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest, macOS-latest]

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Node ${{ matrix.node }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}

      - name: Install deps and build (with cache)
        uses: bahmutov/npm-install@v1

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
```

`release.yml` action:

```
# Name of the workflow
name: Release new version

# Run on every commit tag which begins with "v" (e.g., "v0.1.4")
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*"

jobs:
# Automatically publish a NPM release
  npm-publish:
    name: NPM Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node ${{ matrix.node }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node }}
      - name: Install deps and build (with cache)
        uses: bahmutov/npm-install@v1
      - name: Publish
        run: npm publish
        env:
          NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}

# Automatically create a GitHub Release, with release details specified (the relevant commits)
  github-release:
    name: Github Release
    needs: [npm-publish]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' }}
    steps:
      - uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          prerelease: false
```

Comment: You show the workflow files but you don't share on which branch those are with exactly that content nor about for that tag. Unless the tag you push has these workflows, they'll never run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your if condition inside the jobs. `if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' }}`
In case of tags push, `github.ref` will be something like `refs/tags/v.2.2.2`
Since the if condition is not matching the jobs are skipped.

I ran a sample job here to validate it. [Link](https://github.com/heyitsvajid/actions-test/runs/7483466463?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I trigger the action if two conditionals are met: On push tags (which already exists) and on push to the master branch?

Comment: A tag is not created "on" a branch. A tag is just something that points to something. Therefore, what you probably could do is listen for created tags and then check if the current sha ($GITHUB_REF) points to the top of master.

Comment: Could you please share an example?